# Android cardView - how to fill in corner colors?

Tags: android, android-cardview

Usually people want to remove the color around the corner radius if a card view but i want to keep it. i currently have a cardview that look like this:

[image]

and i know it looks great but what i want to happen is for the corners to be filled in with another color,. how can i achieve this ?

here is the code i have so far:

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/my_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/_ribbon_pink_1"
    android:foregroundTint="@color/_green"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="200dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">
```

How to fill in the corners with another color so that it looks something like thislike this with the corners filled in with another color:
[image]

would like to do this without adding a background as in with a framelayout.

Comment: Use `android:background` in a parent view (as a simple LinearLayout).

Comment: i wish there was a command without doing background. i thought of that right away.  any other way can do it without a background ?

Answer (score 0):

- try this.

  ```
   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
       android:id="@+id/card"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
       card_view:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
       card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
       card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

       <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:padding="@dimen/item_title">


           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/title"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:minHeight="@dimen/item_cover_height"
               android:text="title text test"
               android:textSize="@dimen/item_title"
               android:textStyle="bold" />


       </RelativeLayout>

   </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
  ```